# Java and Dynamic Type

Tags: java, types, casting

Suppose you have the two classes:

```
public abstract class X {
  public abstract void insert(Object item);
}

public class Y extends X {
  protected Object a;
  public void insert(Object item) {
    a = item;
  }
}
```

When you try the following:

```
X x = new Y();
x.insert(5);
```

Everything is fine. However, when you also add

```
x.a;
```

Why do you have to do:

```
((Y) x).a;
```

for that last line?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

> However, shouldn't the compiler recognize that the dynamic type of x is actually Y?

No, the compiler doesn't analyze the program to determine the dynamic types of variables. At **compile time**, it works only with static types.

> It seemed to understand this for the second line, since the insert method actually does end up giving x a value for "a".

Method resolution is done at **run time**, where dynamic typing is possible. This is not the compiler doing the resolution, but the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

method/field resolution is done based on the type of the reference variable (X in this case).  'a' doesn't exist on X so you have to cast to Y to tell the compiler to treat that reference as a Y reference instead and so can resolve 'a'.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding is irrelevant here. Static binding is the important thing.

Your object has the static binding of type `X`, as you define your object eas `X x = ...`. The compiler does not know any `a` in that type.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you have this code :

```
public abstract class X {
  public abstract void insert(Object item);
}

public class Y extends X {
  protected Object a;
  public void insert(Object item) {
     a = item;
  }
}
public class Z extends X {
  public void insert(Object item) {
     /* nothing */
  }
}

// method signature : public X someSecretBlackBoxMethod()
X x = someSecretBlackBoxMethod();
```

Now, that `someSecretBlackBoxMethod` method returns a concrete instance of a class extending `X`, right? So which one is it, `Y` or `Z`?

Well, the compiler doesn't know either. This is why the compiler cannot resolve `x.a`. However, if you cast it into `Y` (i.e. `((Y)x).a`) then the compiler *knows* that `x` *should* be an instance of `Y` and, therefore, know about the attribute. Now, at run-time, if `x` is *not* an instance of `Y`, then you got a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).